# split() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to predict the Viscosity of plastic fluid, I used  Random Forest Regressor and K-Fold cross-validation to train my data.

```
RFR = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 2000,max_depth = 20, n_jobs=-1, random_state = 0)

scores = []
Kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state = 0, shuffle=True)

for i in range(10):
    result = next(Kfold.split(X_train), None)
    input_train = df.iloc[result[0]]
    input_test = df.iloc[result[1]]
    output_train = y.iloc[result[0]]
    output_test = y.iloc[result[1]]
    model = RFR.fit(input_train,output_train)
    predictions = RFR.predict(input_test)
    scores.append(model.score(input_test,output_test))
print('Scores from each Iteration: ', scores)
print('Average K-Fold Score :' , np.mean(scores))
```

I want ta train my model for 10 fold cross-validation, but I got this error message :

```
TypeError: split() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggestes, [`StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html)'s `split` method is expecting both `X` and `y` from the training data in order to generate the validation and test sets:

> split(self, X, **y**, groups=None)

Comment: When I add y, I got this message :

Comment: ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead.

Comment: Not sure without more details/data  @sb... Hope this helped u continue from here. Don't forget you can upvote and accept :)